# Postgres: missing or erroneous pg_hba.conf file

Tags: postgresql, configuration

I have 2 machines sitting on my desk and connected to the same IP network. I'm trying to connect an application from one machine to the postgres database on the other. 
At first the host with the application on it was giving me the PSQLException:

```
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.1.18", user "user1", database "test", SSL off
```

So I edited my pg_hba.conf file to accept the IP address: 192.168.1.18, by adding the line below at the end of the file:

```
host    pnp         all         192.168.1.18      trust
```

Then I got another type of error message:

```
FATAL: missing or erroneous pg_hba.conf file
```

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Thanks,
Lancelot

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to specify the netmask of the host too. So either "`192.168.1.18/32`" or "`192.168.1.18 255.255.255.255`" instead of the bare IP address.

See [the pg_hba.conf file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) chapter in the online manual for details.